# How to make CareKitUI Bar Charts compatible with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable, carekit

Currently, there is limited support for [CareKit](https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKit) using SwiftUI.

I understand, generally, the idea of making an object conforming to `UIViewRepresentable`, but am struggling to get going with how this would work in practice.

The following is example code from the [readme](https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKit#charts-):

```swift
let chartView = OCKCartesianChartView(type: .bar)

chartView.headerView.titleLabel.text = "Doxylamine"

chartView.graphView.dataSeries = [
    OCKDataSeries(values: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2], title: "Doxylamine")
]
```

So the `init(type)`, `headerView.titleLabel` and `graphView.dataSeries` would need to be set as `@Binding` variables in a struct conforming to `UIViewRepresentable`, but I'm struggling to figure out how I have to use the following two functions:

```swift
func makeUIView() {}

func updateUIView() {}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually only data requires binding, because type is part of initialization and title is hardly possible to be changed, so here is possible variant

```
struct CartesianChartView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var title: String
    var type: OCKCartesianGraphView.PlotType = .bar
    @Binding var data: [OCKDataSeries]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> OCKCartesianChartView {
        let chartView = OCKCartesianChartView(type: type)

        chartView.headerView.titleLabel.text = title
        chartView.graphView.dataSeries = data

        return chartView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: OCKCartesianChartView, context: Context) {
        // will be called when bound data changed, so update internal 
        // graph here when external dataset changed
        uiView.graphView.dataSeries = data
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! However, when I do the following: `CartesianChartView(title: "Glucose", data: OCKDataSeries(values: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2], title: "Doxylamine"))` it returns an error with `Cannot convert value of type 'OCKDataSeries' to expected argument type 'Binding<[OCKDataSeries]>'`. How do I correct this?

Comment: If you don't want to change data later then remove `@Binding` as use it as regular property, otherwise put data either in `@State` property in parent or in some `ObservableObject` view model.